# How to get HTTP POST raw body posted to visulforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, httprequest

I am trying to get the raw body from a http Post request made to a visiulforce page on our site.

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1.

Can someone give me sample piece of code on how retrieve the body from a http post from a visulforce page.

Thanks in advance,
Vishnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an idea posted related to this content. You can look into this for more information.

Workaround:

```
MAP<string, string> params = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
for (string paramname : params.keySet() )
 body += paramname + '=' + params.get(paramname) + '\n';
if (body.endsWith('=\n')) {
 body = body.substring(0,body.length()-2);
}
```

Source : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br5iAAC